# Double quotes in bash variable assignment and command substitution

Tags: bash

I have a few questions about variable assignment and command substitution:

1. Why does `\"<Enter>` add a new line to the output

```
$ v1="1\"
2"
$ echo "$v1"
1"
2
```

?

2. Why

```
$ v2=$(echo -e "123\n\n\n")
$ echo "$v2"
123
```

while

```
$ v2=$(echo -e "123\n\n\n5")
$ echo "$v2"
123


5
```

?

3. How to correctly use quotes in such constructs:

```
v3="$(command "$v2")"
```

?

Comment: Why do you think 3 is incorrect? It's not.

Comment: What is surprising about #1?

Comment: #2 is documented: command substitutions drop any trailing newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

## First question

< Enter > equal to `new line`, also equal to `\n`.
Use following code to explain:

```
function print_hex() {
    HEXVAL=$(hexdump -e '"%X"' <<< "$1")
    echo $HEXVAL
}

v1="
"
v2=$'\n'

print_hex $v1
print_hex $v2

---------output---------
A
A
```

In hex mode printing it is seen that `v1` and `v2` are equal.

## Seconde question

echo manual explain [link](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo).

```
-e    enable interpretation of backslash escapes
-E    disable interpretation of backslash escapes (default)
```

## Third question

Do you mean print the string or mean get the command output?
The following example v3 is print the string and v4 is get the command output.

```
v2=.
v3="\$(ls \"$v2\")"
v4=$(ls "$v2")
echo $v3
echo $v4

---------output---------
$(ls ".")
test1.sh
```